# Strore div into database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have create board with `div` tag, I want after drop images take the div (board) to another page and the image hide in same place I put

**[html](/questions/tagged/html):**

```
<html>
<div id='grid' name="grid">
  <div class='row'>
    <div id='cell0' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell1' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell2' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell3' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell4' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell5' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell6' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell7' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell8' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <div id='cell9' class='cell' ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
  </div>

</html>
```

**[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):**

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
window.allowDrop = function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (ev.target.getAttribute("draggable") == "true")
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed

  else
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'store div to database'? Do you need to store entire cells (with innerText) to a DB? What does your DB table look like? The information provided is insufficient to answer your question

Comment: I want to store the number of div that I drop the image on it to database

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the div's ID into the DB, it should be able to call it from the event target

```
function drop(e) {
    // assuming e.target is the div
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.target.id); //store into DB
}
```

If you want to save the image you dropped into the div in the DB, follow this article:
https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_draganddrop.asp

One tip: You shouldn't store the image, but it's path. So you to set the path as data

Comment: I want after drop images take the div (board) to another page and the image hide in same place I put

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand what you want. You have a row of divs. In a div you want to drop an image. To which page should the div go and where should the image "hide"??? Do you have an example website for it? Where the effect is already visible?